# Enable/disable input field depending on array length in Angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im new to Angular 1.5. I want have an array and when it is empty, I want to disable an input field. When it's not empty, I want to enable the field. But it's not working as expected. I've put together a simple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdhzr1am/1/).

```
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController() {
    var vm = this;
    this.data = ['a', 'b'];

    setInterval(function() {
        if (vm.data.length === 0) {
            vm.data = ['a', 'b'];
        } else {
            vm.data = [];
        }
        console.log('vm.data is now ', vm.data);
    }, 2000);
}
```

And

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-disabled="!data" />
  <br />
  data is {{ data }}
</div>
```

I would expect each time the `setInterval()` method is executed, the HTML would be updated, so the input would cycle between enabled and disabled. But doesn't work and the template isn't outputting the data array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using controller instance you need to use its alias `mainCtrl`, To check if `data` is empty or not check its `length` property.

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-disabled="mainCtrl.data.length ==  0" />
  <br />
  data is {{ mainCtrl.data }}
</div>
```

Also, You should use [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) instead of `setInterval`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldg3bm57/2/)

Comment: _"I would recommend you to use $interval"_ It's **necessary** to use `$interval`.

Comment: That's why I wrote it's necessary.